# Webix template, in lines

Tags: webix

I want to show all lines of my data. in webix with view template

[enter link description here](https://snippet.webix.com/3ociljea)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not use templates for arrays. Templates are for data in objects.
Use list: https://snippet.webix.com/0si9lnkm

Also as far as I can tell, type:"line" does not exist https://docs.webix.com/api__ui.template_type_config.html

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use type: 'line',
Only need to make a html before.

https://snippet.webix.com/wysmmtov

Comment: You can add the code here, instead of posting the link to snippet.